# Firebase App Check on a Flutter app doesn't have the Enforce ability

Tags: flutter, firebase-app-check, flutterflow

I'm trying to enable App Check on a Flutter app.

I found this webpage here:
https://docs.flutterflow.io/settings-and-integrations/project-setup/firebase/app-check
Where I started following the instructions and did what I saw in the videos.
That is:

- enable app check in the Google Play Console
- register the app in App Check section of Firebase

The next video clicks on the APIs tab, then clicks on Cloud Firestore so the Enforce button can be clicked.

However, I can't click on *anything* in the APIs tab and I can't figure out why. I did everything the webpage told me to do.

If someone could provide insight into what I need to do I'd be greatful!